# Send mails to 5-10 users when a Discussion is created

Tags: 2010

i need to send an email when a discussion is created .
I have added a "assigned to " field where i specify the users wh wil take part in discussion .
I need to send email to these users and also the person who created the discussion .hw is it possible in sp 2010 ?

Answer (score 2):

Using a workflow in Sharepoint Designer, on creation, send an email.  In the To section, add the Assigned To field and CC the Created by person.  Add whatever you want into the message body.